# Can the Ethereum network be used as a database

Tags: ethereum

Can we use the Ethereum network just like a database to store data. What might be the possible issues that can occur if it is used as a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just write a smart contract to store and retrieve your data.

Google the term "Solidity CRUD" for articles and tutorials for storing data in on Ethereum.

The downsides are:

1. Speed - Blockchains are slow to write and not fast to read. Ethereum will never be able to compete with even low performance databases like SQLite much less go against Postgres, Oracle or MongoDB.
2. Cost - Reading from Ethereum is free but writes cost Ether. The exact cost depends on the size of the data you want to store. For small amounts of data this does not matter much. For services you can even make this part of the API that your users will pay writes (such as buying a ticket form you) so it doesn't cost you anything. But if you have gigabytes of legacy data migrating it to the blockchain can be very expensive.

   On top of that, doing large data transfer to the blockchain will see demand for transactions spike which will increase the cost per transaction. This is not just theoretical, it has happened before - when the cryptokitties smart contract was launched the game suddenly became so popular that transactions went from less than one cent per transaction to tens of dollars per transaction (USD).

In general you'd want to store only the core data that you need to be secure on Ethereum and link it to other data sources (for example store a URL link and hash of the object but store the object itself on Amazon S3 or Azure Storage)